# need to do a file system at particular file location in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Actually I am trying to do zip conversion and need to save zip at particular folder as zip_folder created with my project folder. This is happening when I call some api. I can't able to do but if I use __dirname its working properly. Can anyone help me to comeout from this by giving your solutions. Thank you.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const archiver = require('archiver');
var file1 = '../zip_folder/scorm.zip';
var onlyPath = require('path').dirname('C:\Users\is9115\Desktop\node_moodle');
const mysql = require('../shared/connection');
// create a file to stream archive data to.

const archive = archiver('zip', {
 zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
});

async function createzip()
{
    
    const output =  fs.createWriteStream(file1); // this is not working at file location
    const output =  fs.createWriteStream(__dirname+'/scorm.zip');//working but creating at root folder itself

fs.readFile('imsmanifest.xml', 'utf-8',async function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var newValue = data.replace(/Var_Title/g, 'Golf');

   fs.writeFile('imsmanifest1.xml', newValue, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Done!');
})
})

archive.pipe(output);
const file2 = __dirname + '/imsmanifest1.xml';
archive.append(fs.createReadStream(file2), { name: 'imsmanifest.xml' });
archive.append('string cheese!', { name: 'file2.txt' });
archive.directory('scorm12schemadefinition/', false);
archive.file('imsmainfest1.xml', { name: 'imsmanifest.xml' });
archive.finalize();
```

}